# SDE/brownian motion with drift

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Let

$dX_t = \mu dt + \sigma dW_t$. I need to calculate the solution of this SDE.
So I know that the solution of this sde is the brownian motion with drift:
$X_t = x_0 + \mu t +\sigma B(t) $

Now I need to calculate the conditional distribution $X_{t+\Delta t} | X_t $

I know that since $B(t) \sim N (0,t) $ and if $Y(t)=\mu t + \sigma B(t)$ then $Y \sim N(\mu t, {\sigma}^2 t)$ however here we would be having an additional $+x_0$. so would the distribution of $X(t) \sim N(\mu t+x_0, {\sigma}^2 t)$ ?

However I still don’t know how to yield the conditional distribution $X_{t+\Delta t} | X_t $

And I further would need to calculate $\mathbb{E} (X_{t+\Delta t} | F_t)$ and

Edit with the information from the comments:

$X_{t+\Delta t} = X_t + \mu \Delta t + \sigma (W(t+\Delta t) - W(t))$

So I set $V_t = \mu \Delta t +  \sigma (W(t+\Delta t)-W(t))$
And I came to the conclusion that $V_t \sim N(\mu \Delta t, {\sigma}^2 \Delta t)$ (right?) and $X_t \sim N(\mu t+x_0, {\sigma}^2 t)$, and $X_{t+\Delta t} = X_t + V_t$.
But would $X_t$ and $V_t$ be independent?

Comment: There can be no $t$ in the variance, as the interval of uncertainty is only $Δt$ long.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, so if $X(t) = xo + \mu t + \sigma B(t)$ , then I thought $X(t) \sim N (\mu t + x_0, {\sigma}^2 t)$ (is this wrong? Because I only meant the distribution of the brownian motion with drift at this stage and not yet the conditional distribution?)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Now shift the origin to $t,X_t$.

Comment: So the origin is now at $x_0$? ? So then it would need to remove the constant term $x_0$? I‘m sorry could you elaborate more how I could this?

Comment: You apply the same idea to $X_{t+Δt}=X_t+μΔt+σ(W_{t+Δt}-W_t)$. Remember that also the Brownian increments are Gaussian, and that for the conditional expectation $X_t$ is constant.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: I edited the post with new calculations.